# Access & Change Value Within a String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, filter, hue

Quick question:

Below goes the code of a JS exercise/experiment on **changing two DIV's hue values on click** (#left and #right). I've managed to mostly set it up, and get it running, but I've run against a problem when both **trying to access the current hue value** and **change that hue** of the target element, as the return of *e.target.style.filter* is a **string** *"(hue-rotate(Xdeg))"* **instead of a value**.

Accessing and modifying the value within the string would allow me to increment the **current e.target hue value** gradually and console.log it - 360º, but I have no idea how to do that. I know how to do it externally *("hue-rotate(" + X + "deg)")* but not when it comes to me already as a string.

Code goes below.

```
let l = 60;
let r = 60;

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(occurence => {
  occurence.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.id == "left") {
      l += 40;
      if (l>360) {l-=360}
      e.target.style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + l + "deg)";
    }
    else if (e.target.id == "right") {
      r += 40;
      if (r>360) {r-=360}
      e.target.style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + r + "deg)";
    }
    console.log(e.target.id + " is " + e.target.style.filter);
  });
});
```

*(For those interested, [this question has been expanded to a working version of the code presented above and some additional questions on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416949/forcing-if-condition-within-function-to-run-every-time)).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the current value:

```js
const myFilter = "hue-rotate(95deg) blur(4px) ..."

// the filter CSS rule can contain multiple filter-functions,
// separated by a whitespace
let degrees = myFilter
                 .split(" ") // split the whitespace-separated string into  an array of strings
                 .find(f => f.includes("hue-rotate")) // find the hue-rotate function
                 ?.replace(/\D/g, "") // replace all (/g) non-numerical characters (\D) with nothing ("")

console.log(degrees)
// 95
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess working with regular expressions is just down the road on my JS course, haha.