# Forcing If Condition Within Function to Run Every Time

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

So, I've built a [quick function to change hue values of a target element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389661/access-change-value-within-a-string-in-javascript) in JavaScript, and it works mostly fine now, but I do have some more questions that go beyond the initial post's scope. So I'll open a new question and post them here.

Here's the code:

```
document.getElementById('left').style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + 20 + "deg)";
document.getElementById('right').style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + 20 + "deg)";

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(occurence => {
  occurence.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const filter = e.target.style.filter;
    var deg = parseInt(filter.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
    deg += 40;
    e.target.style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
    if (deg >= 360) {deg -= 360}
    console.log(e.target.id + " is " + deg + "deg");
 });
});
```

My **main question (1)** is that I've coded an **if statement to log the current hue value within 360º** (the hue-rotate works anyway with values over +360º, but I find it to be clearer this way). However, while the check works perfectly the first time around, it **stops working after the function loops once through the 360º** (on subsequent loops, it goes beyond 360º).

For clarification, the statement has been positioned after the degree value is already set (and animated) so as to sidestep the quick loop animation that happens when it goes from, say, 340 to 20º (instead of going there directly, it seems to loop back through the whole hue wheel).

Also, **(2)** the initial hue-rotate states are **defined (at the top) within the script** because the function *does not work* otherwise, although **both DIVs do have defined CSS values**.

That's it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is much harder to reason about w/o the accompanying DOM elements. It's not clear why `deg` is modified *after* setting `filter`; the modification is thrown away when the function ends.

Comment: Well if deg is worth 1080 it does not work anymore, you need to do ```deg = deg % 360``` not ```deg = deg - 360```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the degree value on the element is always set before limiting the degrees to 360, the 2nd time it loops subtracting 360 wont be enough.

```
style      logged value
0          0
360 (-360) 0
720 (-360) 360
etc
```

To limit the logged value between [0, 360], use the % operator instead

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(occurence => {
  occurence.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const filter = e.target.style.filter;
    var deg = parseInt(filter.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
    deg += 40;
    e.target.style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
    deg %= 360; // deg = deg % 360
    console.log(e.target.id + " is " + deg + "deg");
 });
});
```

---

For (2):
To get the style of the element from css, use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
occurence.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const filter = getComputedStyle(e.target).filter;
  ...
});
```

Comment: This throws away the modification to `deg`. Wouldn't it make more sense to set `filter` w/ the modified `deg` value?

Comment: since the element has an animation on the filter, setting the rotation to a lower value would result in the animation running in reverse. The modification to `deg` could be used for displaying a nice degree value as text inside the element, but in the question (and here) it is only logged to the console

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean 

Comment: You're the man. Quick, clear, and easy answer to both questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   e.target.style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
```

above line should be below if condition    `if (deg >= 360) {deg -= 360}`

```js
document.getElementById('left').style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + 20 + "deg)";
document.getElementById('right').style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + 20 + "deg)";

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(occurence => {
  occurence.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const filter = e.target.style.filter;
    console.log(filter);
    let deg = parseInt(filter.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
    deg += 40;
    if (deg >= 360) {
      deg -= 360
    }
    e.target.style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + deg + "deg)";

    console.log(e.target.id + " is " + deg + "deg");
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="right">right</div>
```

Comment: Having the line below the condition will make the animation on `filter` for the element go in reverse when `deg` is set from 340 to 20